# Java XML DOM: Why does Java XML Attr.isId() return false when it should return true

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have an xsd file with a section like this:

```
<xsd:complexType name="tDefinitions">
    <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:ID" use="optional"/>
```

I am creating a DocumentBuilder like this:

```
private final DocumentBuilderFactory _docBldF = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

....

public synchronized void addSchema(String schemaUri) {
    if(!_schemaUris.contains(schemaUri)){
        _schemaUris.add(schemaUri);
    }
    Source[] allSources = new Source[_schemaUris.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < allSources.length; i++) {
        allSources[i] = new StreamSource(_schemaUris.get(i));
    }

    Schema schema;
    SchemaFactory scFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    try {
        schema = scFactory.newSchema(allSources);
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    _docBldF.setSchema(schema);
    _docBldF.setNamespaceAware(true);
}

....

exec.addSchema(getClass().getResource("model/xsd/some.xsd").toURI().toString());
```

and here's how I load the XML:

```
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = _docBldF.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = dBuilder.parse(xml);
        document.normalizeDocument();
```

then I am walking around this doc:

```
    definitionsElement = document.getDocumentElement();
    NodeList defNodes = definitionsElement.getChildNodes();
    .....
```

And now I want to know the ID of an element:

```
    NamedNodeMap attrs = element.getAttributes();
    String id = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < attrs.getLength(); i++) {
        Attr attr = (Attr) attrs.item(i);
        if (attr.isId()) {
            id = attr.getValue();
            break;
        }
    }
```

The `isId()` returns false even if in the debugger I see:

```
attr.getSchemaTypeInfo().getTypeName().equals("ID") // true
```

and other traces that the schema was actually loaded.

Please advise what I am missing as I think I am doing everything I should in the correct order: loading an XSD, setting namespace awareness, normalizing the document.

The XSD has multiple imports and includes and still seems to be loaded correctly with all of them.

The addSchema is called only once now but is intended to be called multiple times with different XSD files and is thought to be able to adapt the DocumentBuilder to load XML files of any format (schema) that we would have added. I would expect it to corrupt the Doc Builder when called second time, but now it is called only once...

**upd**
Just for fun:

```
_document.getElementById("some_id").getAttributeNode("id").isId() // return false
```

The parser is able to locate an element by its id, but can't tell that the id attribute is an id. On my level of knowledge I consider this impossible, please help

As a workaround, I am going to check whether

```
attr.getSchemaTypeInfo().getTypeName().equals("ID")
```